# Prevent unecessary line break

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, format, prettier, vetur

I'm kinda lost with the whole eslint/vetur/prettier config, how do I prevent this from happening ? It make the code take a lot more space, pushing neighboring stuff out of view.
PrintWidth won't change anything.

(note : theses are two different exemples stitched in Paint, the space between is not part of my issue)
[Line break nightmare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i1Fd.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.